# Sum values from table by date

Tags: mysql, date, sum, mariadb

I am stuck with an MySQL / MariaDB problem. I have found some solutions for PostgreSQL but unfortunately I couldn't convert it to MySQL.

I have a table with dates and values and would like to sum them by date.

Example:

```
date       | value
2019-08-01 |  50
2019-09-01 |  30
2019-10-01 |  20
```

Result from a query should add up all values in a date.

```
date       | value
2019-08-01 |  50
2019-09-01 |  80
2019-10-01 | 100
```

Can someone help me out with this SQL? Thanks

Comment: It is important to state the version of mysql you are on. In 8.0 and above some features were added which would be useful in this question.

Comment: Server-Version: 10.2.27-MariaDB - MariaDB Server

Comment: It's also important to tag the question correctly. MARIADB is a fork of mysql and a mysql answer might not work in mariadb.

Comment: I think the answer should be something like a one/or two liner. It can't be that hard and I don't think that there are some newer functions necessary, so version and mariadb/mysql shouldn't matter (I guess)

Comment: However, MariaDB 10.2 had CTEs and windowing functions long before MySQL 8.0 came out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use the features available in this case windows functions https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/window-functions/ but you could use a correlated sub query

```
Drop table if exists t;
create table t
(dt date, amount int);
insert into t values
('2010-10-01',30),
('2010-11-01',20),
('2010-12-01',50);

select t.*,(select sum(amount) from t t1 where t1.dt <= t.dt) cumamount
from t;

+------------+--------+-----------+
| dt         | amount | cumamount |
+------------+--------+-----------+
| 2010-10-01 |     30 |        30 |
| 2010-11-01 |     20 |        50 |
| 2010-12-01 |     50 |       100 |
+------------+--------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SUM`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sum/) as a window function to get the running total on each date. You can also remove duplicate rows with `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `date`, SUM(`value`) OVER (ORDER BY `date` ASC) AS `value`
FROM example
ORDER BY `date`
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=f940e08dd974ee80a380d2c3481e507e)